# How to highlight words in a text file

Tags: highlighting

I would like to highlight particular parts of the text using **cat**. How is this possible?
The answer is **cat filename | grep word**
Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you use cat inside pico? Or, do you want to highlight text in pico whichout using cat? I dontt understand...

Comment: I created a text file and I would like to, specifically, use the **cat** command to highlight particular words, and I have removed pico from the description as it had no relevance.

Comment: `cat` is not `grep`

Comment: Yes thank you for clearing that up @Ipor Sircer the question is can I use **cat** to do it?

Comment: Well... cat stands for concatenate. "Cat" is a solution to the "highlight problem". May you just tell us, why you want to do this? May be highlight can be a solution. May be grep...

Comment: @TomScott Why do you want to do it with cat?!?

Comment: I am working on an assignment in computing and can't find any helpful answers on the internet. I have created a text file called tomtextfile with about 100 words in it. he next question is 'Use the cat command, suitably modified, to: show the contents of tomtextfile, with every occurence of a word, chosen by you, highlighted'
I am new to Linux and these forums and I was just wondering if anyone could help? :)

Comment: *Specific word.

Comment: Now I see... But, I must confess, I can't see the point... :-( Maybe in combination with grep? (What ever "suitably modified" means...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, or should be: **Not possible**.

```
Usage: cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Concatenate FILE(s) to standard output.

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

  -A, --show-all           equivalent to -vET
  -b, --number-nonblank    number nonempty output lines, overrides -n
  -e                       equivalent to -vE
  -E, --show-ends          display $ at end of each line
  -n, --number             number all output lines
  -s, --squeeze-blank      suppress repeated empty output lines
  -t                       equivalent to -vT
  -T, --show-tabs          display TAB characters as ^I
  -u                       (ignored)
  -v, --show-nonprinting   use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

Examples:
  cat f - g  Output f's contents, then standard input, then g's contents.
  cat        Copy standard input to standard output.

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/cat>
```

The 'core' function of cat is to concatenate - literally. in other words - anything that does not **concatenate**  - or *link (things) together* - should be considered superfluous

Comment: While your assignment might be to use 'cat' - the assignment is wrong. **cat** is a program with historical perspective. something such as cat * (for multiple files) | sed sed_argsORPrgs would be a more *nix approach imho

Comment: Well, it is my GCSE so I'd hope that it can be done.